# Wordpress Archive Sorts Events By Post Date, NOT Event Date

Tags: php, wordpress, events, post

I have been battling with WordPress for weeks over this issue and just can't figure it out.  Maybe one of you guys can help me out...

I am using WordPress to manage department sites for a California university and I keep running into the same problem when it comes to events.  Basically I would like a page which archives all the event posts BY EVENT DATE (which is set within the post itself), but it keeps posting the archive by post date.  The link to get to the archive is structured as follows:

http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/news_events/?category_name=events

So, it's specifying the archive to only show the posts with the category event, but it's not displaying them in the order I would like.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I can provide code upon request.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. A website with an agenda where the event date is stored by ACF as a meta info. Actually it is saved as a timestamp value (not a MySQL date type) because it is a DateTime Picker field.

I made the following modifications:

1. Create a modified copy of wp_get_archives to manage the agenda
   archives counting. My new function wp_get_archives_mdv is located in
   functions.php. SQL queries modified to include the join to the
   wp_postmeta table, and only past events.
2. I made copies of the filters getarchives_where and getarchives_join
   whic are called from wp_get_archives_mdv (this could actually be
   avoided by hardcoding     the SQL senteces but it seemed cleaner to
   me)
3. Create a modified copy of get_the_date to manage the archived event
   date when called from archive.php.
4. Finally, hooked on pre_get_posts to adjust the query issued by the
   archives.php loop.

I provide the code just in case anyone could be interested.

**wp_get_archives**

```
/**
 * Display archive links based on type and format.
 * for events of MDV. Adapted from WP 4.4 wp-includes/general-template.php
 * @return string|void String when retrieving.
 */
function wp_get_archives_mdv( $args = '' ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp_locale;

    $defaults = array(
        'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => '',
        'format' => 'html', 'before' => '',
        'after' => '', 'show_post_count' => false,
        'echo' => 1, 'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $r['post_type'] );
    if ( ! is_post_type_viewable( $post_type_object ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $r['post_type'] = $post_type_object->name;

    if ( '' == $r['type'] ) {
        $r['type'] = 'monthly';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $r['limit'] ) ) {
        $r['limit'] = absint( $r['limit'] );
        $r['limit'] = ' LIMIT ' . $r['limit'];
    }

    $order = strtoupper( $r['order'] );
    if ( $order !== 'ASC' ) {
        $order = 'DESC';
    }

    // this is what will separate dates on weekly archive links
    $archive_week_separator = '&#8211;';

    // over-ride general date format ? 0 = no: use the date format set in Options, 1 = yes: over-ride
    $archive_date_format_over_ride = 0;

    // options for daily archive (only if you over-ride the general date format)
    $archive_day_date_format = 'Y/m/d';

    // options for weekly archive (only if you over-ride the general date format)
    $archive_week_start_date_format = 'Y/m/d';
    $archive_week_end_date_format   = 'Y/m/d';

    if ( ! $archive_date_format_over_ride ) {
        $archive_day_date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
        $archive_week_start_date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
        $archive_week_end_date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
    }

    $sql_where = $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = 'publish'", $r['post_type'] );

    /**
     * Filter the SQL WHERE clause for retrieving archives.
     *
     * @since 2.2.0
     *
     * @param string $sql_where Portion of SQL query containing the WHERE clause.
     * @param array  $r         An array of default arguments.
     */
    $where = apply_filters( 'getarchives_events_mdv_where', $sql_where, $r ,$args);

    /**
     * Filter the SQL JOIN clause for retrieving archives.
     *
     * @since 2.2.0
     *
     * @param string $sql_join Portion of SQL query containing JOIN clause.
     * @param array  $r        An array of default arguments.
     */
    $join = apply_filters( 'getarchives_events_mdv_join', '', $r );

    $output = '';

    $last_changed = wp_cache_get( 'last_changed', 'posts' );
    if ( ! $last_changed ) {
        $last_changed = microtime();
        wp_cache_set( 'last_changed', $last_changed, 'posts' );
    }

    $limit = $r['limit'];

    if ( 'monthly' == $r['type'] ) {        
        $query = "SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)) AS `year`, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)) AS `month`, count(ID) as posts";
        $query = $query . " FROM $wpdb->posts $join";
        $query = $query . $where . " GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value))" ;
        $query = $query . "ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value $order $limit"; 

        $key = md5( $query );
        $key = "wp_get_archives_mdv:$key:$last_changed";
        if ( ! $results = wp_cache_get( $key, 'posts' ) ) {
            $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
            wp_cache_set( $key, $results, 'posts' );
        }

        if ( $results ) {
            $after = $r['after'];
            foreach ( (array) $results as $result ) {
                $url = get_month_link( $result->year, $result->month );
                if ( 'post' !== $r['post_type'] ) {
                    $url = add_query_arg( 'post_type', $r['post_type'], $url );
                }
                /* translators: 1: month name, 2: 4-digit year */
                $text = sprintf( __( '%1$s %2$d' ), $wp_locale->get_month( $result->month ), $result->year );
                if ( $r['show_post_count'] ) {
                    $r['after'] = '&nbsp;(' . $result->posts . ')' . $after;
                }
                $output .= get_archives_link( $url, $text, $r['format'], $r['before'], $r['after'] );
            }
        }
    } elseif ( 'yearly' == $r['type'] ) {
        $query = "SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)) AS `year`, count(ID) as posts";
        $query = $query . " FROM $wpdb->posts $join";
        $query = $query . $where . " GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value))" ;
        $query = $query . "ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value $order $limit"; 


        $key = md5( $query );
        $key = "wp_get_archives_mdv:$key:$last_changed";
        if ( ! $results = wp_cache_get( $key, 'posts' ) ) {
            $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
            wp_cache_set( $key, $results, 'posts' );
        }
        if ( $results ) {
            $after = $r['after'];
            foreach ( (array) $results as $result) {
                $url = get_year_link( $result->year );
                if ( 'post' !== $r['post_type'] ) {
                    $url = add_query_arg( 'post_type', $r['post_type'], $url );
                }
                $text = sprintf( '%d', $result->year );
                if ( $r['show_post_count'] ) {
                    $r['after'] = '&nbsp;(' . $result->posts . ')' . $after;
                }
                $output .= get_archives_link( $url, $text, $r['format'], $r['before'], $r['after'] );
            }
        }
    } elseif ( 'daily' == $r['type'] ) {
        $query = "SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)) AS `year`, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)) AS `month`,DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)) AS `dayofmonth`,  count(ID) as posts";
        $query = $query . " FROM $wpdb->posts $join";
        $query = $query . $where . " GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value)),DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value))" ;
        $query = $query . "ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value $order $limit";

        $key = md5( $query );
        $key = "wp_get_archives_mdv:$key:$last_changed";
        if ( ! $results = wp_cache_get( $key, 'posts' ) ) {
            $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
            wp_cache_set( $key, $results, 'posts' );
        }
        if ( $results ) {
            $after = $r['after'];
            foreach ( (array) $results as $result ) {
                $url  = get_day_link( $result->year, $result->month, $result->dayofmonth );
                if ( 'post' !== $r['post_type'] ) {
                    $url = add_query_arg( 'post_type', $r['post_type'], $url );
                }
                $date = sprintf( '%1$d-%2$02d-%3$02d 00:00:00', $result->year, $result->month, $result->dayofmonth );
                $text = mysql2date( $archive_day_date_format, $date );
                if ( $r['show_post_count'] ) {
                    $r['after'] = '&nbsp;(' . $result->posts . ')' . $after;
                }
                $output .= get_archives_link( $url, $text, $r['format'], $r['before'], $r['after'] );
            }
        }
    }  

    elseif ( 'weekly' == $r['type'] ) {
        $week = _wp_mysql_week("FROM_UNIXTIME(`meta_value`)");
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT $week AS `week`, year(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value) ) AS `year`, count(ID) as posts";
        $query = $query . " FROM $wpdb->posts $join";
        $query = $query . $where . " GROUP BY $week, year(FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_postmeta.meta_value))" ;
        $query = $query . "ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value $order $limit";

        $key = md5( $query );
        $key = "wp_get_archives_mdv:$key:$last_changed";
        if ( ! $results = wp_cache_get( $key, 'posts' ) ) {
            $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
            wp_cache_set( $key, $results, 'posts' );
        }
        $arc_w_last = '';
        if ( $results ) {
            $fechai  = new DateTime();
            $fechaf  = new DateTime();
            $after = $r['after'];
            foreach ( (array) $results as $result ) {
                $fechai ->setISODate($result->year, $result->week);
                $fechai->setTime(0,0,0);
                $fechaf ->setISODate($result->year, $result->week); 
                $fechaf->setTime(0,0,0);
                $fechaf->modify('+7 day');

                $arc_year       = $result->year;
                $arc_w_last     = $result->week;

                $arc_week_start = date_i18n( $archive_week_start_date_format, $fechai->getTimestamp () );
                $arc_week_end   = date_i18n( $archive_week_end_date_format,$fechaf->getTimestamp ());
                $url            = sprintf( '%1$s/%2$s%3$sm%4$s%5$s%6$sw%7$s%8$d', home_url(), '', '?', '=', $arc_year, '&amp;', '=', $result->week );
                if ( 'post' !== $r['post_type'] ) {
                    $url = add_query_arg( 'post_type', $r['post_type'], $url );
                }
                $text           = $arc_week_start . $archive_week_separator . $arc_week_end;
                if ( $r['show_post_count'] ) {
                    $r['after'] = '&nbsp;(' . $result->posts . ')' . $after;
                }
                $output .= get_archives_link( $url, $text, $r['format'], $r['before'], $r['after'] );

            }
        }
    }    
    elseif ( ( 'postbypost' == $r['type'] ) || ('alpha' == $r['type'] ) ) {
        $orderby = ( 'alpha' == $r['type'] ) ? 'post_title ASC ' : 'data DESC, ID DESC ';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts $join $where ORDER BY $orderby $limit";
        $key = md5( $query );
        $key = "wp_get_archives_mdv:$key:$last_changed";
        if ( ! $results = wp_cache_get( $key, 'posts' ) ) {
            $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
            wp_cache_set( $key, $results, 'posts' );
        } 
        if ( $results ) {
            foreach ( (array) $results as $result ) {
                if ( $result->data != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) {
                    $url = get_permalink( $result );
                    if ( $result->post_title ) {
                        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
                        $text = strip_tags( apply_filters( 'the_title', $result->post_title, $result->ID ) );
                    } else {
                        $text = $result->ID;
                    }
                    $output .= get_archives_link( $url, $text, $r['format'], $r['before'], $r['after'] );
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    if ( $r['echo'] ) {
        echo $output;
    } else {
        return $output;
    }
}
```

**getarchives_where and getarchives_join**

```
function my_archives_join_filter($join) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $join . "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)";
}
add_filter('getarchives_events_mdv_join', 'my_archives_join_filter');


function my_archives_where_filter($where,$args) {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = current_time( 'timestamp');
    $post_type  = isset($args['post_type'])  ? $args['post_type']  : 'agenda';          
    $where  = "WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = '$post_type' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key ='data' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <='$data'";
    return $where  ;
}
add_filter('getarchives_events_mdv_where', 'my_archives_where_filter',10,3);
```

**get_the_date**

```
function get_the_date_event_mdv ( $d = '', $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( '' == $d ) {
        //$the_date = mysql2date( get_option( 'date_format' ), get_field('data') );
        $the_date = date_i18n (get_option( 'date_format' ),get_field('data'));
    } else {
        //$the_date = mysql2date( $d, get_field('data') );
        $the_date = date_i18n ($d,get_field('data'));
    }

    return $the_date;
    // This filter is not implemented i MDV modification. return apply_filters( 'get_the_date', $the_date, $d, $post );
}
```

**pre_get_posts hook**

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // exit out if it's the admin or it isn't the main query 
    if (is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query())
    {
        return $query;
    }

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'agenda', 'page' ,'professorat'));
      }
    }

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'agenda' ) ) 
        {
            // Set the posts_per_page to 9 = 3*num_agenda_linia
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3*num_agenda_linia);     


            if (is_date()) 
                { 

                if ($query->query['w']!='' ) 
                    {                   
                    if ($query->query['year']=='')      
                        {$year=date("Y");}
                    else                                
                        {$year=$query->query['year'];}

                    $fechai = new DateTime();
                    $fechai->setISODate($year, $query->query['w']);
                    $fechai->setTime(0,0,0);

                    $fechaf = new DateTime();                   
                    $fechaf->setISODate($year, $query->query['w']);
                    $fechaf->setTime(0,0,0);
                    $fechaf->modify('+7 day');


                    $meta_query = array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        data_clause1=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  current_time( 'timestamp')  
                        ) ,
                        data_clause2=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'value'     =>  $fechai->getTimestamp ()
                        ),
                        data_clause3=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  $fechaf->getTimestamp ()
                        )                   
                        );                      

                     $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query); 

                    $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'data');
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');  

                    unset($query->query_vars['year']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['day']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['w']);                 
                    }               
                elseif  (is_month())
                    {         
                    $meta_query = array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        data_clause1=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  current_time( 'timestamp')  
                        ) ,
                        data_clause2=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'value'     =>  mktime(0,0,0,$query->query['monthnum'],1,$query->query['year']) 
                        ),
                        data_clause3=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  mktime(0,0,0,$query->query['monthnum']+1,1,$query->query['year'])   
                        )                   
                        );                  
                    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);  

                    unset($query->query_vars['year']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['day']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['w']);          
                    }                   
                elseif (is_year())
                    {   
                    $meta_query = array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        data_clause1=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  current_time( 'timestamp')  
                        ) ,
                        data_clause2=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'value'     =>  mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$query->query['year']) 
                        ),
                        data_clause3=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$query->query['year']+1)   
                        )                   
                        );                  
                    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);  

                    $query->set( 'order' , 'desc' );
                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'data');
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');    
                    unset($query->query_vars['year']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['day']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['w']); 
                }
                elseif (is_day())
                {                                        
                    $meta_query = array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        data_clause1=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  current_time( 'timestamp')  
                        ) ,
                        data_clause2=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'value'     =>  mktime(0,0,0,$query->query['monthnum'],$query->query['day'],$query->query['year'])  
                        ),
                        data_clause3=> array(
                        'key'       => 'data',
                        'type'      => 'CHAR',
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'value'     =>  (mktime(0,0,0,$query->query['monthnum'],$query->query['day']+1,$query->query['year']))
                        )                   
                        );                  
                    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);  

                    $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'data');
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');  

                    unset($query->query_vars['year']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['monthnum']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['day']);
                    unset($query->query_vars['w']); 
                }   

                elseif (is_category() && $evolve_category_page_title) 
                {} 
                elseif (is_tag()) 
                {}

                }
            else
                {    
                $meta_query = array(
                    data_clause=> array(
                    'key'       => 'data',
                    'type'      => 'CHAR',
                    'compare'   => '>=',
                    'value'     =>  current_time( 'timestamp')
                    ) 
                    );                  
                $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);  

                $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
                $query->set( 'meta_key', 'data');
                $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');      

                }               
        }


  return $query;
}
```

Bye

Zulok

Answer (score 0):

How is EVENT DATE being handled and stored?

I would query EVENT DATE with an added filter and pass the sort order

```
Function query_posts
```

Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

How to sort archive.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
    function my_change_sort_order($query){
        if(is_archive()):
         //If you wanted it for the archive of a custom post type use: is_post_type_archive( $post_type )
           //Set the order ASC or DESC
           $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
           //Set the orderby
           $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        endif;    
    };
```

Answer copied from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/sort-results-by-name-asc-order-on-archive-php

If plugins are acceptable, you can also try this:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/archive-posts-sort-customize/

(Not affiliated to link)

For the future, you should consider posting to http://wordpress.stackoverflow.com